# 1 index in list disappears and replaces 0 index

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a `JList` with multiple items in it, item at 0 index and an item at 1 index.  When I click on the item in the 1 index it disappears and it becomes the item at 0 index, does anyone know why?

```
rightSelectedRow = rightJTable.getSelectedRow();
```

Comment: Provide some more code and preferably a minimum test case.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line.

Comment: @Dukeling [have to read](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment), hmmm then action by mood is more than suprice